# In Kleene algebras, is $1\le 0$, $0\le 1$, or $0=1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

There's an apparent inconsistency in the definition of a Kleene algebra.

Let $A$ be a Kleene algebra. Then there exist $0,1\in A$ such that

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
1a & = a1 & = a \\
0a & = a0 & = 0
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

for all $a\in A$.

The partial order is defined by $$a\le b \iff a+b=b,$$ so it's pretty clear that $$0+1=1 \implies 0\le 1.$$ For those of us used to working with 0 and 1, this is not a surprising result.

We then have a function $^*:A\to A$ that must satisfy this axiom (among a few others):

$$1+x(x^*)\le x^*$$

for all $x\in A$.  However, this implies that

$$1+0(0^*)\le 0^*$$

and

$$1\le 0.$$

Since $\le$ is a partial order, the implication is that $1=0$, but then for some nonzero $z\in A$ such that $z\ne 1$,

$$z=1z=0z=0,$$

a contradiction.  What's up?

Answer (score 3):

What's up is that $$0^*\ne 0.$$

We frequently think of the Kleene star as "zero or more of the operand," but this doesn't mean that $0^*=0$ because zero repetitions of something is equal to 1 in Kleene algebras, not zero.

Another way to think about the Kleene star that makes this even more obvious is the following sum:

$$x^*=1+x+xx+xxx+xxxx+xxxxx+\cdots$$

See also: [$0^0=1$](http://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/10005.3-5.shtml).

Comment: I'm glad there's no "how long did it take you to figure this out" field when answering your own question.

Comment: Can it be proven that, that sum holds in any Kleene Algebra? I understand it's being used for intuition, but does the equality hold in-general? It is used as the definition of star in Quantales; but what about KAs?